# Is there any way to make a self defined class support key autocomplete in vscode-jupyter enviroment?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

Key autocompletion works for dict and pd.DataFrame. How could I make it works for my self defined class like

```py
class mydict:

    def __init__(self, _dict) -> None:
        self._dict = _dict

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._dict[key]
```

For `dict`
[image: The key 'aa' exist]

For `mydict`
[image: The key 'aa' does not exist]

I have try to search it in Google but found nothing related discussion and solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a static analysis challenge.

The question starts with another question: Do you want IntelliSense to suggest to you something that it knows statically (before running any code and only by looking at the information in the source code) is possibly a key of a given instance of your object type in *any* code path leading to the suggestion-trigger-site? Or guaranteed by *all* code paths leading to the suggestion-trigger-site? This is a design question dependent on context and use-case (you are not the only user of VS Code and your use-case and context is not the only use-case and context that exists in the universe)

Even after answering that question, then you have to accept the obvious limitations of the choice that you make. Say you receive an instance of this object as a function parameter. If you want to get IntelliSense for this parameter, then you will need to get either a union or intersection of the guarantees from all the code paths where the function is called. And even then, there will be code paths where your dictionary type is populated with values that are not determinable statically- for example, read from user input at runtime.

And regardless of whether you care about guarantees from any or all code paths, then you have to deal with the additional challenge from the fact that it is not possible for static analysis to know in what order you will run code cells (you may run some multiple times, in non-sequential order, and skip cells), and that it doesn't know what state the kernel is in.

So yes, you could get suggestions from static analysis for extremely simple cases. But there are a lot more complicated cases than there are simple ones, and they range from difficult to impossible to give you suggestions for.

It seems that the Python and Jupyter extensions in VS Code just opt for the simplest thing for `dict` types, which is to suggest a key that is used anywhere in the code for that dict regardless of ordering of events. That's not necessarily a bad thing, but there are arguments for and against.

As for related issue tickets, you may be interested to read these:

- https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1993 "intellisense for **getitem** return values
  #1993"
- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1318 If your key type is a closed set of values, you can use `Literal` from `typing`.

You could raise an issue ticket of your own asking for such a feature.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.